# DSL Using ConnectionProvider and ExecuteListeners

Tags: jooq

I am switching my code to use a Connection Provider rather than a configuration.  In the process, I have lost the use of my custom execute listener which I use to log my SQL statements.

So a couple questions:

1. Is there a way to use a custom listener if I am using a
   connectionProvider?
2. Is the configuration not even needed?
3. What do I put in the "release" method?

   ```
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userName, password );
       conn.setSchema( schema );

       configuration = new DefaultConfiguration().set( conn ).set( SQLDialect.MYSQL );
       configuration.set( new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider( new IFSCustomJOOQExecuteListener( true, true ) ) );

       aDSL = DSL.using( configuration );
   ```

I switched it over and now it looks like this:

```
    IFSConnectionProvider ifsConnectionProvider = new IFSConnectionProvider();
    aDSL = DSL.using( ifsConnectionProvider, SQLDialect.MYSQL );
```

Here is the code of the connection provider (with non-relevant lines removed):

```
    public class IFSConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider
        {
        protected Connection conn;
        protected Configuration configuration;

        @Override
        public Connection acquire() throws DataAccessException
            {
            try
                {
                if (conn == null)
                    {
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userName, password );
                    conn.setSchema( schema );
                    conn.setAutoCommit( false );

                    configuration = new DefaultConfiguration().set( conn ).set( SQLDialect.MYSQL );
                    configuration.set( new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider( new IFSCustomJOOQExecuteListener( true, true ) ) );
                    }
                return conn;
                }
            catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                ... yada yada yada ...
                }

            }

        @Override
        public void release( Connection connection ) throws DataAccessException
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // do i need to do a release?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that are worth mentioning here:

> I am switching my code to use a Connection Provider rather than a configuration

You're still using a configuration. Because under the hood, there's always a configuration, even if it is created for you, wrapping your connection provider.

> 1. Is there a way to use a custom listener if I am using a connectionProvider?

The two things are unrelated. In any case, at some point you will need to put both in your configuration

> 2. Is the configuration not even needed?

Yes it is needed. The question is whether you need to create one yourself. You don't need to, if you're just passing a connection provider to `DSL.using()` (which is just convenience API! It creates the configuration for you).

But if you want to use an execute listener, you'll need to create a configuration yourself, manually.

> 3. What do I put in the "release" method?

In your case, you will never do anything in the release method, because you created a standalone connection yourself. The logic that created the connection should close it, not jOOQ (i.e. not "release")

> ```
> public class IFSConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider
>         {
>         protected Connection conn;
>         protected Configuration configuration;
> ```

I'm afraid this won't be going anywhere for two reasons:

1. You probably shouldn't cache the connection in your connection provider. I don't see why that would be useful.
2. The connection provider is what you put inside of the configuration. It doesn't make sense to go the other way round.

I think the entire question is caused by a misunderstanding of jOOQ's various SPIs:

1. There is always a configuration
2. If you don't create it yourself, jOOQ's convenience methods will create it for you
3. Configurations contain ConnectionProviders, not vice versa.